# iPhone. Com port communication

Tags: iphone

Is it possible that the iPhone can somehow send data or some control command to the computer's com ports via USB cable? Maybe use inline assembly language for instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried, but I'm sure its possible in OS3.0 and higher using the accessories development kit http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/accessories/ as this allows you to communicate via the 30pin dock connector.